# What is Aggregate in Xcode, and mainly use to do?

Tags: ios, xcode, frameworks, aggregate

My primary questions as the title.

1. Since Xcode 6 added the Dynamic Framework, whether means I can just have the one target created by `Cocoa Touch Framework` to generate a framework without library.
2. Whether the `Aggregate` target means if I want to generate a universal and multiple architectures framework I must use this target? And is that the target primary purpose?

That's all. Thanks.